# variable initialization failure

Tags: android, android-volley

As we know asynctask works as a background thread and returns control to the gui when task is complete and requests through volley can be made in the main activity thread , 
Lets say i assign the JSON response to a string variable upon the completion of the request , the string is initially null , the program further processes that reponse,
the problem that i got was i was thrown a NullPointerException while processing the response string even after the successful response , 
it would be absurd to say but is it possible if the response is slow the program may continue without initializing the string variable ??

Comment: Probably you should post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are not using a proper callback on your data. In other words, after you start AsyncTask, you have to wait until it is done until you reference global variables that it might impact.

So, if you didn't write a proper callback method, then yes the program will continue. The idea behind AsyncTask that - to let the thread it is called on continue while it does a long process of some kind.